# How to make triangles with rounded sides and corners? (squircle with 3 sides)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting, illustrator-effects

[image]

Methods likes this [Rounded corner shape with rounded sides](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16580/rounded-corner-shape-with-rounded-sides) Don't really work for triangle.

So now I'm thinking what's the best way to make this shape, so I can control the radius of roundness at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Select the triangle and press <kbd>A</kbd> to activate the Direct
  Selection Tool
- Make a selection frame around the triangle
- Use the Live Corner Widget to round the points

[image: round corners]

- Press <kbd>A</kbd> to activate the **Direct Selection Tool**
- Make a selection frame around the bottom points
- Click the **Convert Selected Anchor Point to Smooth** icon at the top bar options
- Repeat with the top point

[image]

Comment: Can I change each corner handle length at the same time?

Comment: Automatically? I don't think so. That's vector drawing.

Comment: @Michael One would expect that selecting each point and then performing **[Transform Each](https://opusdesign.us/blog-post/adobe-illustrator-using-transform-each/)** would scale the Bézier handles relative to the individual points, but it does not. [Here's how it *should* be.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/individual_origins.html) Oh well :-p

Comment: @Michael Might be worthwhile having a look at [Inkscape functionality shown here](https://imgur.com/a/Kk7JdPr).  It has a stars and polygon tool with live editable corners/curves that can be adjusted. Saved as SVG, the shapes could be then imported into Illustrator.